# How to get double precision value in python equals to java Float.valueof()

Tags: python, java, double

I am trying to migrate a java calculation to python, where I see the difference in the float value calculation results

for example: in Java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long lg_val =  Long.parseLong("16191753860");
        float fg_val = Float.valueOf(lg_val);
        System.out.println(fg_val);
    }
}
```

result - 1.61917542E10 (prints the double value)

but in python float() method returns same value 16191753860.0

How to get the double-precision calculation in python to get the same results

Comment: A Java float is single precision (using 4 bytes) while a Python float is double precision (8 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

The python `float` is a double precision floating point number. It is in fact your Java example that is using the single precision `float`, which is why it formats in scientific notation (as it has gone above integer precision).

If you want to print out the scientific notation of a float in python regardless of if it's crossed over the precision boundary, use the `e` format.

`f'{lg_val:e}'` -> `'1.619175e+10'`

---

Or to use a double precision number in Java instead, use

```java
double fg_val = Double.valueOf(lg_val);
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I have to migrate the existing java implementation to python.

Comment: still the values are not padding similar to the return value of Java Float.valueof

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.float64()`. In your example,

```
import numpy as np 

np.float64(lg_val)
```